# Mysql, inner join in multiple columns with the same name

Tags: mysql, inner-join

So, I have two tables, one of which is like this:

Table: `data`

```
  id  |   col_1   |   col_2   |   col_3   |   col_4
------------------------------------------------------
  1   |     167   |    12     |     15    | something1
  2   |     198   |    27     |     12    | something2
  3   |     253   |    15     |     17    | something3
```

and Table: `catalog`

```
  id  |   col_1
-----------------
  12  |   red
  15  |   yellow
  17  |   pink
  27  |   green
```

Now, what I am trying to do is get `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3` and `col_4` from the `data` table, but instead of getting the values of `col_2` and `col_3`, these should be replaced by the `col_1` of the `catalog` table, according to the `catalog` `id`.

For example, I want it to return, for every row of the data table, the following info:

```
    167 | red    | yellow | something1
    198 | green  | red    | something2
    253 | yellow | pink   | something3
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT data.col_1, catalog.col_1, catalog.col_1, data.col_4
FROM data
INNER JOIN catalog ON data.col_2 = catalog.id
INNER JOIN catalog ON data.col_3 = catalog.id
```

but to no effect and surprise.

I simply can't find how to inner join multiple columns of one table to a single column of another, and Google has not been of great help. I actually don't know if I am searching with the right keywords.

Comment: You must be using an out-of-date version of google. This is SQL 101. Each instance of `catalog` requires its own alias.

Comment: But what would happen if a col in `data` has an id not present in `catalog`?

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe he uses Bing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the tablenames an alias, because it doesn't know where catalog refers to.

```
SELECT data.col_1, c1.col_1, c2.col_1, data.col_4
FROM data
INNER JOIN catalog c1 ON data.col_2 = c1.id
INNER JOIN catalog c2 ON data.col_3 = c2.id
```